# How to find all of the indices for all unique elements in a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, loops

Given the following list:

```
list_ex = ['s1', 's2', 's1', 's4', 's2', 's3', 's1']
```

How can all the indices of all the distinct elements, be found?

For example, for `s1`, this would be locations `[0, 2, 6]`.

I think that I can do this by running a loop over the distinct elements `list(set(list_ex))`, and then do a `np.where` to find the location?

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through the elements, building up a dictionary mapping elements to the list of indices for that element. Using a `defaultdict` of type `list` is convenient for this because you automatically get an empty list when reading a new element for the first time.

```
from collections import defaultdict

list_ex = ['s1', 's2', 's1', 's4', 's2', 's3', 's1']

indices = defaultdict(list)

for i, v in enumerate(list_ex):
  indices[v].append(i)

print(indices)
```

This prints the following:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'s1': [0, 2, 6], 's2': [1, 4], 's4': [3], 's3': [5]})
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found that `pandas` seems to be optimized for this kind of problem.

```
import random
import pandas as pd
x = [f's{i}' for i in range(1000)]
l = [random.choice(x) for _ in range(2000000)]
output = pd.DataFrame(l).groupby([0]).indices
```

It can be 3 times faster than `enumerate` in optimal scenarios (sizes of groups are large) and 3 times slower in cases where sizes of groups are small (1 - 2 items per group).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short solution using a list comprehension:

```py
locations = [el[0] for el in enumerate(list_ex) if el[1] == "s1"]
```

**Explanation**

Enumerate creates a list of location / element pairs, it looks like this:

```
[(0, 's1'), (1, 's2'), (2, 's1'), (3, 's4'), (4, 's2'), (5, 's3'), (6, 's1')]
```

This code below gets the same result, it's just showing it in a for loop form:

```py
target = 's1'
locations = []

for el in enumerate(list_ex):
    if el[1] == target:
        locations.append(el[0])
```